# What is the correct way to pop up a window with a message, and locally bind a key in that buffer?

Tags: buffers, help, popup

What would be the proper way to pop up a window (preferably in the current frame),with a message? I also want to locally (in that buffer only) the `q` key to a function that will kill the buffer and the window (similar to what is done in IELM's error pop-ups, but it won't be an error pop-up).

I have tried this:

```
(defun kill-buffer-and-window ()
  (kill-this-buffer)
  (if (not (one-window-p))
      (delete-window)))

(defun cool-message ()
  (interactive)
  (pop-to-buffer "*cool-message-buffer*")
  (use-local-map (make-sparse-keymap)) ; don't change bindings for other buffers
  (local-set-key "q" 'kill-buffer-and-window)
  (insert "Yo!!!"))

(local-set-key "x" 'cool-message)
```

I know that `local-set-key` will change the binding for all buffers using the same major-mode -- this is just a quick hack to show what I want.

The problem is that hitting `q` in the buffer that pops up will not kill it.

What did I miss?  Do I need to create a minor mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **`with-help-window`**:

```
(with-help-window "*My Help Buffer*" ; Whatever buffer name you like.
   ;; Use `princ`, `prin1`, `terpri`, etc. to put text in the displayed buffer
)
```

Key `q` will automatically be bound to do what you want.

`C-h f with-help-window` says:

> **`with-help-window`** is a Lisp macro in `help.el`.
>
> `(with-help-window BUFFER-OR-NAME &rest BODY)`
>
> Evaluate `BODY`, send output to `BUFFER-OR-NAME` and show in a help window.
>
> This construct is like `with-temp-buffer-window` but unlike that
>   puts the buffer specified by `BUFFER-OR-NAME` in `help-mode` and
>   displays a message about how to delete the help window when it’s no
>   longer needed.  The help window will be selected if
>   `help-window-select` is non-`nil`.
>
> Most of this  is done by `help-window-setup`, which see.

As that suggests, you can alternatively use `with-temp-buffer-window`.

(Or you can use `(with-output-to-temp-buffer BUFFER . BODY))` instead of `(with-help-window BUFFER . BODY)`.)

Comment: Thank you!!! That is perfect, will use it.